# Sufficient condition for symmetric matrices to be an orthogonal projection matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, symmetric-matrices, projection-matrices

I am trying to prove a version of Cochran's theorem(Theorem 5.14)  [given here](http://users.stat.umn.edu/%7Esandy/courses/8311/handouts/ch05.pdf)

**The problem:-**

Let $A_1, A_2, \cdots , A_m$ be  $n\times n$ symmetric matrices and $A = \sum_i A_i $ with $\text{rank}(A_j)$$=n_j$. Then, 
If

1. $A_jA_k=0,\forall j\ne k$
2. $\sum n_j= \text{rank}(A)$ ( should $\text{rank}(A)$ be further constrained to be equal to $n$?? )

Then,

1. $A_j$ is an orthogonal projection for all $j$.

**What i have tried:-**

$$\text{Since, each  } A_i\text{ is symmetric }\implies N(A_i) = (C(A_i))^{\perp}  \tag{a}$$
$$\because A_jA_k=0,\forall j\ne k\implies C(A_i)\cap C(A_j)=\{0\}  \tag{b}$$
$$\because (A = \sum A_i)\text{ and (b)} \implies Ax = A_i x, \forall x\in C(A_i)  \tag{c}$$
$$\because A_jA_k=0,\forall j\ne k\implies A^2 = \sum A_i^2\text{ and } A^2x = A_i^2 x, \forall x\in C(A_i)   \tag{d}$$
$$\because (A = \sum A_i) \implies C(A) \subset C(A_1)+C(A_2)+\cdots\cdots+C(A_m)  \tag{e}$$
$$\because \sum n_j= \text{rank}(A) \implies \dim C(A) = \dim C(A_1) + \dim C(A_2)+\cdots\cdots+ \dim C(A_m)  \tag{f}$$
$$\because \sum n_j= \text{rank}(A) \text{ and (e) and (f) } \implies C(A_i)\cap\big(\bigcup_{j\ne i}C(A_j)\big)={0} \tag{g}$$

$(e)+(f)+(g) \implies C(A) = C(A_1)\oplus C(A_2)\oplus \cdots \cdots \oplus C(A_m) \tag{h}$

$C(A) = $column space of $A$; $N(A) = $null space of $A$

Comment: First, complete the assumptions : $A$ is assume to be an orthogonal projection. Then note that the range of $A$ is the direct sum of the ranges of the $A_j$. Given a vector $x$, writing the decomposition of $Ax=A^2x$ in two different way help to see that the $A_j$ are projectors.

Comment: @ChristopheLeuridan none of the matrices are assumed to be orthogonal projections. For clarifications, kindly have a look at theorem 5.14 through the link provided in my question above.

Comment: It looks strange. The assumptions would be preserved by a multiplication by a real number whereas the conclusion is not preserved. I do think that $A$ should be assumed to be a projection, whatever Theorem 5.14 in your reference pretends.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $n=4$ let $$A_1=\begin{pmatrix} 2 & 1& 0& 0\\
1 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0& 0 & 0\\
0 & 0& 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix} \quad A_2=\begin{pmatrix}0 & 0& 0 & 0\\
0 & 0& 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 2 &  1\\
 0 & 0 & 1 & 1
\end{pmatrix}$$
and $A=A_1+A_2.$
Then $A_1A_2=A_2A_1=0,$ $\operatorname{rank}(A_1)=\operatorname{rank}(A_2)=2$ and $\operatorname{rank}(A)=4.$
None of the matrices is a projection or a multiple of a projection.